# put variable in bold with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I would like to put variables (inside a select) that I retrieve from a mysql database with php in bold(or italic). I tried the two following ways, and also with , but it doesn't work?
In this example it tried to put everything bold, but I actually want only $row['test'] in bold. Thanks!

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['ptname'].$row['test'];?>">
    <span style="font-style:italic">
        <?php echo $row['ptname']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['test'];?>
    </span>
</option>

<option value="<?php echo $row['ptname'].$row['test'];?>">
    <?php echo '<b>'.$row['ptname']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['test'].'</b>';?>
</option>
```

Comment: Please consult your HTML Reference of choice first, to learn about why the code you've pasted does not work. Then make clear what you did expect - should it have worked? If so, why? If not, what is your question exactly? And why doesn't any of the other questions that seem to cover the same topic didin't help you so far?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this question was already asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

the way to do it is to use some fake "dropdwon looking" construction with JS.

Take a look at [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), it is simple to use and gives you many options.

Answer (score 0):

This  will work but only in Firefox not in chrome or other

```
<style>
.ItalicOption{font-style:italic;}
.BoldOption{font-style:bold;}
</style>
<option value="<?php echo $row['ptname'].$row['test'];?>"><span class="ItalicOption"><?php echo $row['ptname']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['test'];?></span></option>

<option value="<?php echo $row['ptname'].$row['test'];?>"><?php echo 
'<b>'.$row['ptname']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['test'].'</b>';?></option
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['ptname'].$row['test'];?>">
    <?php echo $row['ptname']."&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>".$row['test']."<b>";?>
</option>

<option value="<?php echo $row['ptname'].$row['test'];?>">
    <?php echo $row['ptname']."&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>".$row['test']."</b>";?>
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php echo '<i><b>'.$row['ptname']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['test'] . '</b></i>';?>
```